# NodeJS predefined SQL query filter security patch

Tags: sql, mysql, node.js, reactjs, sql-injection

I have this query, that is written in NodeJS React.

```
const lftAds = await this.LftAdRepository.manager.query(`
        SELECT lft.id, lft.user_id, lft.description, lft.x, lft.z, lft.y, lft.k, lft.languages, user.username, user.profile_photo
        FROM lft_ad AS lft
        LEFT JOIN users AS user ON lft.user_id = user.p
        ${orderBy ? `ORDER BY lft.${orderBy} ${order || 'ASC'}` : ''}
        ${take ? `LIMIT ${take}` : ''}
      `);
```

As you can see, in the bottom I have conditions like **orderby, order and take**. This is to make it possible to order through my restAPI, like this:

```
/finder/players?orderBy=id&order=desc
```

However, this is probably quite easy to SQL inject. I have tried making it a prepared statement, but it is very hard to keep the conditions inside the query that way.

Does anybody have a good idea on how to keep these filters, but patching a potential SQL injection?